# Setting default checked value in ZendFramework2 to RADIO input (QuickStart form)

Tags: forms, radio-button, zend-framework2, checked

Unfortunately i don`t have the exact example here, but, is similar to this:

```
$form->add(array(
         'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
         'name' => 'gender'
         'options' => array(
                'label' => 'What is your gender ?',
                'value_options' => array(
                        '0' => 'Female',
                        '1' => 'Male',
                ),
        )
));
```

How can I set a default value to this element? I tried putting this, but didn't work:

```
'attributes' => array(
       'value' => '0'
)
```

Thank's! And, sorry for my poor english! I need to improve it!

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the value under`option`, not attribute.

LIke this :

```
$form->add(array(
     'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
     'name' => 'gender'
     'options' => array(
            'label' => 'What is your gender ?',
            'value_options' => array(
                    '0' => 'Female',
                    '1' => 'Male',
            ),
            'value' => 10, // here
    )
));
```

See this link:[here](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/Element/MultiCheckbox.php#L157.)

`Radio` is just an extension of `MultiCheckbox`

Comment: In my case, my value_options are: array('label' => 'My Label', 'value' => 'F').. if i put the 'value' => 'F', will Work? I dont remember if i tried put this in 'options' option, but i will try! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the **`checked_value`** within the `options` array

```
$form->add(array(
  'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
  'name' => 'gender', // <-- missing comma here also
  'options' => array(
    'label' => 'What is your gender ?',
    'value_options' => array(
      '0' => 'Female',
      '1' => 'Male',
     ),
     'checked_value' => 10,
  )
));
```

You can see this in the [`setOptions()` method of `Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/Element/Checkbox.php) which the `Radio` element extends.

Comment: I couldn't make it work as well :(.. i did this with jQuery.. But, anyway, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct. **value** key in **attributes** is used to set the default checked value.
You just forgot to add a comma after **'name' => 'gender'**
The following code will work for you

```
$form->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
    'name' => 'gender',
    'attributes' => array(
        'value' => '0',
    ),
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'What is your gender?',
        'value_options' => array(
            '0' => 'Female',
            '1' => 'Male',
        ),
    ),
));
```